# Question: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output

Tags: java, android, flutter, native-code

```
package com.example.flutter_app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), "course.flutter.dev/battery").setMethodCallHandler(
      new MethodCallHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
          if (call.method.equals("getBatteryLevel")) {
            int batteryLevel = getBatteryLevel();
            if (batteryLevel != -1) {
              result.success(batteryLevel);
            } else {
              result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Could not fetch battery level.", null);
            }
          } else {
            result.notImplemented();
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }

  private int getBatteryLevel() {
    int batteryLevel = -1;
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      BatteryManager batteryManager = (BatteryManager) getSystemService(BATTERY_SERVICE);
      batteryLevel = batteryManager.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);
    } else {
      Intent intent = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
      batteryLevel = (intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1) * 100) / intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
    }
    return batteryLevel;
  }
}
```

My java code is given above. I was following a tutorial of writing native java code to get the battery level in my flutter app.

But it gives me the error given below:
(Debug console output)

```
Launching lib\main.dart on LDN L21 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
C:\Users\ARPC\flutter_app\android\app\src\main\java\com\example\flutter_app\MainActivity.java:22: error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FlutterEngine
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
                                           ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Kindly tell me what I am doing wrong I thought that I have to turn **verbose** to true but I don't know how to do that if someone knows the solution please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below code in manifest file

```
meta-data
android:name="flutterEmbedding"
android:value="2"
```

and run the project it will work

Comment: Flutter documentation says "Don't delete the meta-data below. This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java". When I delete the suggested lines, I get an error saying "Build failed due to use of deprecated Android v1 embedding." :(